# How to add column with Twitter users followers count to dataframe in R?

Tags: r, twitter, merge, count

I've created a data frame containing the usual columns from the twitteR package, but I'd like to add a column with the followers count of the corresponding Screen Names in my data frame. How do I do this?

I'm quite new to R. I've already tried and successfully managed to get the tweets_artist1_df$screenName info into a list with the lookUpUsers function and create a new dataframe with all the info of the ScreenNames of the tweets dataframe, but I want to just add the followers count to the dataframe I created earlier.

```
library(twitteR)

## artist 1 search
tweets_artist1 <- searchTwitter("anitta OR #anitta OR @anitta", 
                               n=100000, 
                               since='2019-03-29', 
                               until='2019-04-05', 
                               lang = 'en', 
                               resultType = 'mixed')
tweets_artist1_df <- twListToDF(tweets_artist1)
tweets_artist1_df$text <- sapply(tweets_artist1_df$text,function(x) iconv(x,to='UTF-8-MAC'))

# trying to get the info of the users from the dataframe
users <- lookupUsers(tweets_artist1_df$screenName)
usersdf <- twListToDF(users)
```

I've already managed to use the match function and combine the matching columns.

```
# match function to give relative position of the users
match(tweets_artist1_df$screenName, usersdf$screenName)

# Subset by square brackets
usersdf$followersCount[match(tweets_artist1_df$screenName, usersdf$screenName)]

# Creating new column
tweets_artist1_df$followersCount=usersdf$followersCount[match(tweets_artist1_df$screenName, usersdf$screenName)]
```

But I'd like to be able to write a function to be able to apply this matching on all the six different dataframes I have got. Any helping writing this piece of code would be very helpful. The twitteR documentation does not help much.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please share sample data with `dput`

Comment: It's a fairly big sample. How do I add the output files to the post? I've got the two objects in txt files. Thanks for your help!